# IntelliJ Sync Eclipse files - Where is this setting saved?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

In IntelliJ there is the option of linking IntelliJ-files with Eclipse-files.

So that changes to dependencies make IntelliJ readjust .project-files and the other way around.

**This setting is chosen when importing the project into IntelliJ.**

Now, i wonder: *Where is this setting saved and is it possible that i can reuse the file where this setting is saved for another IntelliJ-setup where the project is imported without this setting set?*

So that, on the other machine, i do not have to fully re-import the entire project in order to make this setting active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ provides out of the box interoperability with eclipse projects. When you select "linking IntelliJ-files with Eclipse-files" intelliJ stores dependencies in eclipse format (.classpath) so any changes you made in the project can also be seen by eclipse.

On project not imported with this option you can try File -> Project structure -> Modules -> Dependencies (tab) -> select eclipse (.classpath) on Dependencies storage format

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/eclipse_java.html

Every module has a modulename.iml file and when changing this setting the module line mentioning what class-path is being used changes.

Comment: Ah, very interesting. Your answer is not quite exactly what i was looking for but it gave the important hint that allowed me to find where the setting is stored: Every module has a modulename.iml file and in there is a line that mentions what class-path to use. Now knowing about where this can be set in the IDE without having to reimport i could simply test if the file is altered when i change the setting and it is.
Thus i'll accept your answer, but maybe it would be cool if you could edit in that this setting is saved in the file "modulename.iml" in each module!